# Detecting all parts of a parallel payment with IPN

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a parallel payment setup on my dev website, which allows a user to make 2 payments in parallel.  Part 1 of the payment goes to the main website, i.e. the site which the user is paying from, i.e. the website which initiates the paypal payment.  Part 2 of the payment goes to a completely different paypal account which is unrelated to the main website.

I am using ipn.php on my dev server to detect the status of the payment.  When the main sites payment is received (part 1), this is detected by my dev servers ipn.php file.  However, the ipn.php file does not seem to detect the other payment (part 2) which goes to the other paypal account which is unrelated to the main website.  Is this behavior normal for the ipn system, or is there a way to get my dev servers ipn.php to detect both parts of the parallel payment even though part 2 of the payment is going to someone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each individual payment would trigger an IPN based on the account the payment went to.  Sounds like you've got your own IPN configured, but you're only getting an IPN for the payment that comes to you, which would be expected.  The other payment would only trigger an IPN for that receiver if they had IPN configured in their own account.

That said, you can set an IPN for the application within your pay request using the NotificationURL parameter.  This would send an app specific IPN to the URL specified which is separate from the individual payment IPN's that each receiver may or may not get based on their own settings.

So, it sounds to me like you need to setup the NotificationURL for an app specific IPN, and then you can configure IPN within your PayPal account to get more details about the individual payment that comes to you, and then the 3rd party could configure their own IPN based on their needs for the payment that goes to them.

Make sense?

Comment: So I can't use a NotificationURL on my own server to get notified for both payments?

Comment: No, the Notification URL set in Adaptive Payments call is considered an "app specific" IPN.  "Transaction specific" IPN's would be sent to the account where that transaction took place (if IPN is configured on that account.)